# What’s a textbook covering similar content to “Introduction to Probability Models” by Sheldon Ross?

Tags: references, conditional-probability, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, conditioning

I’m taking a class with a instructor using said textbook, and I find the explanations in it lacking.
It’d be great if anyone can offer an alternative book covering similar content (i.e. conditioning arguments, stochastic processes, Markov chains, etc.).